# CSS Variables not work with custom property fallback values

Tags: html, css

I am declaring a custom property in :root like below, but my color not work for me. What I am wrong?

```
:root {
    --color-primary: var(--color-primary, #ffc107);
}
body {
    background-color: var(--color-primary); // background color not work
}
```

Comment: Please see the Document here you can find the detail of how to use Fallback values
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties#custom_property_fallback_values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declaring css variables should be like this:

```
:root {
    --color-primary: #ffc107;
}
body {
    background-color: var(--color-primary);
}
```

Comment: Why can not custom property fallback value? 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties#custom_property_fallback_values

Comment: You should do this:
`body {
    background-color: var(--color-primary, red);`
}`

Answer (score 3):

you need to declare the variable in :root like this:

```
:root {
    --color-primary: #ffc107;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use like as

`:root {--color-primary: #ffc107;} body {background-color: var(--color-primary);}`

Comment: Please following document about custom properties fallback value: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties#custom_property_fallback_values